# Почему не сворачиваются блоки кода match/case в Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, сопоставление-с-образцом

В случае с конструкцией if-elif-else, классами, методами классов, циклами и т. д. есть возможность свернуть блок кода при помощи стрелочек слева. Но в случае с конструкцией match/case такой функционал отсутствует. Мне кажется закономерным, что такая опция должна существовать для всех логических блоков, поэтому странно, что у меня ее нет. Вопрос в том, отсутствует ли эта опция только у меня, или ее впринципе нет для match/case? Если проблема на моей стороне, то как ее разрешить? В настройках напротив Show code folding arrows галочка стоит. Все плагины актуальны, snap пишет, что актуальных обновлений нет. Версия убунту: 22.04

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]